# Kafka avro console consumer is not displaying any messages from kafka connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

Steps followed
Installed/extracted confluent 5.0.0.-2.11

Modified kafka-connect-jdbc/source-quickstart.properties to point to my local db

```
name=test-source-sqlite-jdbc-autoincrement
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
connection.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test?user=root&password=root
mode=incrementing
incrementing.column.name=id 
topic.prefix=sqlite-jdbc
query=select * from customer
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
poll.interval.ms=5000
table.poll.interval.ms=120000
mode=bulk
```

Modified below properties in connect-avro-standalone.properties
    plugin.path=extracted folder of confluent

```
bootstrap.servers=domain:9092
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false 
plugin.path=/home/confluent-5.0.0/
```

After modifying above properties I started zookeeper, kafka, schema registry & kafka connect jdbc and also avro console consumer with below command. Table referred: Customer

```
sh kafka-avro-console-consumer --bootstrap-server ip:9092 --topic sqlite-jdbc-customer --from-beginning
```

i do not see any messages in the avro console consumer

Comment: Are you sure that your source connector is up and running?

Comment: I started schema registry and kafka connect jdbc and i see below messages.

`Schema registry
 INFO Started @4834ms (org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server:411)
 INFO Server started, listening for requests... (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain:45)`
-------------
kafka connect jdbc
 `INFO Advertised URI: http://domain:8083/ (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:267)
 INFO REST server listening at http://domain:8083/,
 INFO Kafka Connect started (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:55)`

Comment: How did you load/run your source connector?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous what do you mean by source connector. Is it Kafka Connect JDBC or schema registry or database which has tables?

Comment: `kafka-connect-jdbc/source-quickstart.properties` is the configuration of your source connector (i.e. the connector that replicates data form your MySQL table to Kafka). You need to run this connector in order to achieve this replication.

Comment: How did you start confluent platform? By running `confluent start`?

Comment: yes @GiorgosMyrianthous. I have started source connector using below command
./bin/connect-standalone ./etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties ./etc/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-quickstart-sqlite.properties

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous No we didnt start confluent platform with 'confluent start'. We are starting zk, kafka and schema, connect with individual commands like:
---
to start zookeeper: 
zookeeper-server-start /etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties
---------------
to start kafka:
kafka-server-start /etc/kafka/server.properties

to start schema registry:
bin/schema-registry-start etc/schema-registry/schema-registry.properties

===========================
./bin/connect-standalone ./etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties ./etc/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-quickstart-mysql.properties

Comment: Stop adding lines of code and commands in the comments as they are not readable. If you want to do so, just edit your answer. Can you try to start Kafka Connect and source connector by running `./bin/connect-standalone /etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties /etc/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-quickstart-mysql.properties` ? The command you've used seems to be incorrect. Also share the output of the logs when starting Kafka Connect.

Comment: If you are using `value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter`, then you shouldn't be using `kafka-avro-console-consumer`. In other words, your data wouldn't be Avro, so you shouldn't try to consume in that format.